# DLL Creation from Python source file

Tags: python, dll

Is it possible to create a DLL from a Python source file. I need to reference the DLL generated from Python source file in other Visual Basic Project.

Comment: So you want to execute Python code from Visual Basic? Which Visual Basic? .NET? If yes, check out [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/). If no, good luck... You might want to create a wrapper in C++ with `Boost.Python` or something, but it's not going to be pretty.

Comment: Could you edit this question to be a bit more general and might also be helpful to others? Maybe something along the lines of "How to use Python code in .NET" or "How to use Python code in VB6" (depending on which is what you actually want).

Comment: For DLL injection perhaps? For calling from C or a C derived language?

Comment: @araisbec is it possible to use 'python dll' in c++( vc6 & vc++2010)??